# Show that $λ^{−1}$ is an eigenvalue for $A^{-1}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, matrix-calculus

The given starting point is $Av = λBv$. $A$ and $B$ are two invertible matrices and $v$ is a non-zero vector and $λ$ is a non-zero scalar. I thought about the following:

1. $Av = λBv$
2. <strike>$A = λB$ (divide by v)</strike>
3. <strike>$AB^{-1} = λI$ (multiply by $B^{-1}$)</strike>

I am stuck and don't know how to arrive at $λ^{-1} = A^{-1}B$. What would be the needed steps?

Comment: You cannot divide by a vector. And $λ^{-1} = A^{-1}B$ makes no sense. The LHS is a scalar, the RHS is a matrix.

Comment: I modified the question because the wording was incorrect. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Are you given the equation $Av=\lambda Bv$ as a starting point? As it is, you ask how to show something about $\lambda^{-1}$ without having first defined what $\lambda$ is.

Comment: The equation is given as starting point. We supposedly use the non-zero scalar λ as a way to show that it's inverse is an eigenvalue for  $^{−1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A^{-1}Bv = \lambda^{-1}v $$so $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}B$ with eigenvector $v$ (it was non-zero).

Edit:
$$Av = \lambda Bv $$
multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ from left
$$v = \lambda A^{-1}Bv $$divide by $\lambda$ (it's non-zero because $v\neq 0$)
$$A^{-1}Bv = \lambda^{-1}v $$

Comment: Could you provide the intermediate steps how you arrived to this answer?

Comment: @ReinierKoops sure, here you go

Comment: Thanks, could you explain me why we can disregard $v$ in the answer for eigenvalue because we can't divide by v?

Comment: We actually need the vector $v$ in all of this. We have eigenvalues, then we must have an eigenvector.

Comment: Recall the definition of eigenvalue. We say that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, if there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Av = \lambda v$, and we call $v$ the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. This vector is as important as the eigenvalue itself, but usually all the focus take the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

$$Av = λBv$$
$$A^{-1}Av = A^{-1}λBv$$
$$v = λA^{-1}Bv$$
$$λ^{-1}v = A^{-1}Bv$$

Thus $λ^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue for $ A^{-1}B$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple proof. Since A is invertible multiply both side from the left with $A^{-1}$. You'll get $$Iv=A^{-1}\lambda B v$$
Or 
$$v=\lambda A^{-1}Bv$$.

Here is where you can see that $\lambda^{-1}$ is eigenvalue of $A^{-1}B$.

Since $$v=\lambda A^{-1}Bv$$ and $\lambda \neq 0$, just rewrite $$A^{-1}Bv=\lambda v$$.
This is precisely the definition of eigenvalue.

Comment: Why, when inverting $Av=λ$ you get $=^{−1}$?, say why is $A^{-1}$ not placed at the end?

Comment: Here it is $A^{-1}Av=A^{-1}\lambda B v$. By definition of inverse matrix you have $A^{-1}A=A A^{-1}=I$. Note you can regard it not as an inversion. You just multiply by some matrix which you name as $A^{-1}$ and get the $I$ identity matrix. And identity matrix multiplied by anything of appropriate dimension give the latter.

Comment: You changed a question. That's why.))) First I was answering the question before reformulation.)). Ok let's edit it away.))